# Image slider for c++

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, effect

I have c++ program which display images,

I want to move from one image to another, with nice effect

Do you know any project that can help me?

(For example se the effects inside http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z6PR9AM1vsA
much less than that will be acceptable.)

Thanks.

---------------Edit-------------------

I am using windows xp for develpment, it should also run on XP and windows 7
I am using MFC because it's old project wrriten in MFC many years ago

Comment: This will depend on your platform, since you'll have to draw on the screen, not just produce in-memory bitmaps. What O/S are you on, and what devices do you target?

Comment: And what kind of GUI library are you currently using? (It's probably best to put the answers inside your original question, so people trying to help you don't need to collect all the information they require.)

Comment: The actual terms for that , i believe, are either "coverflow" or "imageflow"; a quick google did not find results (but I've not had my coffee this morning yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an image viewer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/Not_just_a_list_control.aspx) with some of the features you're looking for.   It didn't get the best reviews, but it may help you get started.   Built in VC++/MFC.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a CoverFlow effect project in openGL:
http://blog.csdn.net/beidoustudio/article/details/4090806
I have compiled it and run in MFC.

in file opengl.h has a copyright announcement in simplified chinese:
/*========================================================================
应用：3D 桌面 - CoverFlow 项目概述
作者：段传辉
博客： xxxx
开源： 全部源码开放，若有技术疑问，博客留言。
========================================================================*/

which says 
"
the author name is 段传辉, 
blog is xxxx,
it's open sourced, any question please leave message on the blog.
"